# Consulta jerarquica con dos tablas

Tags: oracle, sql

tengo 2 tablas:

tabla unidades:

```
cd_unidad | cd_unidad_padre
    1     |       -
    2     |       1
    3     |       2
    4     |       2
```

tabla personas:

```
cd_persona | cd_unidad
    1     |       -
    2     |       1
    3     |       2
    4     |       3
```

En la tabla personas cd_unidad es FK de cd_unidad de la tabla unidades.
Lo que estoy intentando hacer es una consulta que me muestre a partir de una persona, todas las personas de su unidad y todas las que estén en unidades por debajo de la suya. De momento tengo esto, pero me saca personas repetidas:

```
  select P.*
  FROM personas P
  LEFT JOIN unidades U ON U.CD_UNIDAD=P.CD_UNIDAD
  start with P.CD_UNIDAD = 2 
  CONNECT by U.CD_UNIDAD_PADRE = prior U.CD_UNIDAD;
```

Este es un ejemplo de lo que sale más o menos:

`level  cd_persona   cd_unidad
2          1           20
3          2           21
3          2           21
3          2           21
3          2           21
3          2           21
3          2           21
3          2           21
3          2           21
3          2           21
2          3           19`

Comment: Podrias mostrar un ejemplo de lo que sale.. y como querrias que saliera?

Comment: ¿Cuantas ramas como máximo tiene esta jerarquía?

Comment: He actualizado poniendo un ejemplo del resultado de la consulta. Ramas en principio no tiene un máximo, pero lo que hay de momento puede llegar a nivel 5 o 6